# Getting error while Creating Case Record Using Odata Rest Services

Tags: javascript, rest, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, dynamics-crm

I have Ribbon button on CustomEntity. CustomEntity has one text field and account lookup Based on the fields i'm Creating case Record. but record was not creating. could anybody help me on this? where i'm doing wrong. Below is my sample

```
function test() {
debugger;
var PostID = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ism_name").getValue();
var ismaccount = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ism_account").getValue()[0].name;
var serverUrl = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host;
var incident = {};
incident.Title = PostID; 
incident.CustomerId = ismaccount;
var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(incident);
//incident.Description = "Dynamicallty created record using REST Odata";
var oDataPath = serverUrl + "/Retail/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"; 
var retrieveReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
var Odata = oDataPath + "/IncidentSet";
retrieveReq.open("POST", Odata, true);
retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "CREATE");
retrieveReq.send(JSON.stringify(jsonEntity));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you give more information like the HTTP response? And what your version of OData? Is that V3 or V4? If it's V3, the request should look like

```
    POST serviceRoot/entityset HTTP/1.1

    DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
    MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;
    Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
    Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
    Accept-Charset: UTF-8

    {
      content of the entity
    }
```

If it's V4, the request should look like

```
    POST serviceRoot/EntitySet
    OData-Version: 4.0
    Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
    Accept: application/json
    {
       "@odata.type" : "namespace.type",
       content of the entity
    }
```

Seems that your code miss the odata version header.

Comment: How to Check Odata Version header?. i'm simply using this code in dynamics crm javascript forms.

Comment: @ppandu you can send a simple GET request and check the response header, it should contain odata version information. If you are not familiar of that, you can use the tool http://www.telerik.com/fiddler.

Comment: if the problem is really  Odata Version means where do i have to modify this in dynamics crm forms javascript?

Comment: @ppandu I think you should just modify the code you provided in the question can work. It seems missing the odata version information.

Comment: And also you can try with fiddler to send the POST request directly to the service to make sure the service can work correctly.